# Adopt flowtype config for webpack resolve.modules setup with multiple module locations

Tags: javascript, webpack, flowtype

Is it possible to configure flowtype (`.flowconfig`) for the following webpack scenario?

My scenario:

I have 2 folders for javascript sourcecode (core and theme), theme is able to override every file from the core scope. So i could have an error logger inside of core but one implementation needs to do very custom stuff, so i would create a logger inside of theme and the webpack module loader would return the theme file instead of the core file.

So i do have 3 locations for modules

- node_modules
- src/js/theme
- src/js/core

When loading something from my source i write `Path/To/Module` instead of `./Path/To/Module`. That works... But i use flow to check my syntax and make some basic qa.

How would i need to adopt my `.flowfonfig` to streamline those configurations?

According to [this source](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-system-node-resolve-dirname-string) i tried:

```
[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=src/js/theme
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=src/js/core
```

But that does not work.

Running flow results in an error for each import i use...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i managed to solve it but i am not happy with the solution.

Instead of adding module directories like shown in my question i added mappers.

```
# mapping theme
module.name_mapper='^Components/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/theme/Components/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Core/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/theme/Core/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Fixtures/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/theme/Fixtures/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Format/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/theme/Format/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Helpers/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/theme/Helpers/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Modules/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/theme/Modules/\1'

# mapping core
module.name_mapper='^Components/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/core/Components/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Core/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/core/Core/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Fixtures/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/core/Fixtures/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Format/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/core/Format/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Helpers/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/core/Helpers/\1'
module.name_mapper='^Modules/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/js/core/Modules/\1'
```

This seems to work!

Note: You have to add a mapper for each (!!!) entry-level